# ManagedExecutorService, ManagedTask and ManagedTaskListener alternative for Java SE

Tags: java, multithreading, guava, java-ee-7, apache-commons-exec

I recently built a Java EE 7 web application using GlassFish / Payara.
The web application started long running tasks (> 2 hours) on the underlying operating system on demand. These tasks are basically other programs or scripts written in Python, Ruby or Java and executed using the command line (Apache Commons Exec). Since I wanted to inform the user about the current state of a task and give him the possibility to cancel a running task I used the following Java EE features and libraries.

The following list briefly describes why I decided to use a specific Java EE feature or an external library.

- **ManagedExecutorService**

  - Injected using @Resource, allowed me to queue Runnables and execute them in an own thread
- **ManagedTaskListener Implementation**

  - This was the reason why I actually decided to use a ManagedExecutorService and run threads within the application server
  - The interface gave me four very handy methods (taskSubmitted, taskAborted, taskDone and taskStarting)
  - This allowed me to update the long running task status (JPA) and inform the user if a state change occurred
- **Runnable, ManagedTask Implementation**

  - Here I defined the actual long running task by overriding the run() method
  - To react on state changes I also registered the ManagedTaskListener implementation as previously described
- **Apache Commons Exec Util**

  - To actually execute the long running tasks the Runnable and ManagedTask implementation simply used apache commons exec
  - To be able to cancel a long running process I set a ShutdownHookProcessDestroyer per DefaultExecutor
  - Using defaultExecutor.getWatchdog().destroyProcess(); this allowes me to kill a running task

I know it is not the best idea to misuse a ManagedExecutorService in combination with ManagedTasks to execute such long running tasks, but it worked pretty stable.

But know I would like to run these long running tasks on a different physical machine and execute them using just Java SE. This means I have no ManagedExecutorService and therefore no ManagedTaskListener interface.

Does anyone have experience with this situation? Maybe there is library which provides similar capabilities. I think Google Guava provides something which goes into a similar direction but does not provide the same capabilities.

I am also thankful for other solution approaches.

Thank you very much!

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."

Answer (score 0):

Use the Java SE executors (i.e. [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html?is-external=true#scheduleAtFixedRate-java.lang.Runnable-long-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-)) to submit a Runnable/Callable that makes the necessary updates.

You will have to implement your own equivalent of `ManagedTask`/`ManagedTaskListener`, but that should be easily achievable through your Runnable/Callable implementations.

Side note:
When you are using a ManagedTask, this is a perfect scenario to set  `ManagedTask.LONGRUNNING_HINT=true` on your ManagedTask.  For example:

```
managedTask.getExecutionProperties().put(ManagedTask.LONGRUNNING_HINT, "true");
```